# Zend Framework error [database connection]

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

Today trying to run my project coded under Zend Framework, and connected to a remote database, i got those 2 errors:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\wamp\www\trunk\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 129

Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\wamp\www\trunk\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 144
```

Before it was working normally, and i don't know what going on with it today.
It seems it's a connection problem to the database but the question, where the problem come from, from the database server, or my project and where excatly.
It's the first time, i got this error, and i really don't know what that mean.

Comment: The DB server is not running or has no network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a network problem to me, try a telnet from the app server:

```
telnet <remote db name/IP> 3306
```

If that fails, you have a network/firewall problem. Or the DB is is not listening on that port or on the network entirely. Do a netstat on the remote DB to confirm:
Linux

```
netstat -an | grep LISTENING
```

Or windows

```
netstat -an | find "LISTENING"
```

You should see :3306 if it's listening on the default port.

Comment: Thank you!, it was a Firewall problem from the server :)